# How to open new tab via javascript after html is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a new tab with javascript after the HTML is fully loaded by the browser. I tried this, but it's not working at all:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(event){window.open('http://www.google.com');});</script>
```

Can you help me out and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: pop up blockers are not going to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a function as the `window.onload` value:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.open('http://www.google.com')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading.

use `load` event

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false);

  function load(){  
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com", '_blank');  
  }
</script>
```

Add `_blank` if you need a new tab. And if you facing problems because of the browser, this link might help [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**AutoExecutaable Functions**
In autoexecutable functions you dont need events or mouse event to execute the functions because the browser execute the function automatically, so do that:

```
(function(w){
   w.open('http://www.google.com');
   //or you can use the following instead window.open
   w.location.href ="http://google.com";
})(window);
```